# WinForms REST API Server With Grapevine

Tags: c#, winforms, rest, grapevine

I would like to add a REST API server to my WinForms application. I have chosen to use Grapveine for that purpose.

Here's my code:

```
namespace RestServerTest
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private RestServer mServer;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      mServer = new RestServer();
      mServer.Start();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
      mServer.Stop();
      mServer.Dispose();
    }
  }

  [RestResource]
  class MyRoute
  {

    [RestRoute]
    public IHttpContext HelloWorld(IHttpContext context)
    {
      // Todo: how access form object from here?

      context.Response.SendResponse("Hello, world.");
      return context;
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I have no idea how to actually access my Form object from the REST route (without using an ugly global/static variable).

How would one do that elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the current form (or any other object/variable in your project) to be accessible to your routes, you can take advantage of [Dynamic Properties](https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine/blob/v4.1.1.0/src/Grapevine/Shared/DynamicProperties.cs). Both the `IRestServer` and `IHttpContext` implement `IDynamicProperties`, which gives you two ways to accomplish your goal.

*Add either of these to your `Form1_Load()` method.*

**Add a Reference On The Server**

```
server.Properties.Add("CurrentForm", this);
```

**Add a `BeforeRouting` Event Handler**

```
server.Router.BeforeRouting += cxt =>
{
    cxt.Properties.Add("CurrentForm", this);
};
```

**Access a Property In a Route**

In either case, you can access the property using the built in extensions methods:

```
// On the server
var form = context.Server.GetPropertyValueAs<Form1>("CurrentForm");

// On the context
var form = context.GetPropertyValueAs<Form1>("CurrentForm");
```